# Matrix VBO's not being picked up by vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl

so my vertex shader takes 3 glm::mat4 objects to render in the correct position. I was drawing each model 1 by 1 passing uniform matrices each render, but the amount of draw calls was starting to slow my framerate. So i changed it to use 3 matrix4 vbo's. Everything now compiles, and I can see some of my objects, but my matrices aren't propagating to the shader. I'd love some help with this if anyone can. My code is as follows,

constants

```
static enum BUFFERS {
        VERTEX_BUFFER, TEXCOORD_BUFFER, NORMAL_BUFFER, INDEX_BUFFER, 
        MVP_MAT_VB, MODELVIEW_MAT_VB, NORMAL_MAT_VB
    };
#define POSITION_LOCATION 0
#define TEX_COORD_LOCATION 1
#define NORMAL_LOCATION 2
#define MVP_LOCATION 3
#define MODEL_VIEW_LOCATION 7
#define NORMAL_MATRIX_LOCATION 11
```

Creating instance vbos

```
MeshEntry::MeshEntry(aiMesh *mesh) {
    vbo[VERTEX_BUFFER] = NULL;
vbo[TEXCOORD_BUFFER] = NULL;
vbo[NORMAL_BUFFER] = NULL;
vbo[INDEX_BUFFER] = NULL;
vbo[MODELVIEW_MAT_VB] = NULL;
vbo[MVP_MAT_VB] = NULL;
vbo[NORMAL_MAT_VB] = NULL;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

elementCount = mesh->mNumFaces * 3;

if (mesh->HasPositions()) {
    float *vertices = new float[mesh->mNumVertices * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; ++i) {
        vertices[i * 3] = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
        vertices[i * 3 + 1] = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
        vertices[i * 3 + 2] = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * mesh->mNumVertices * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    delete vertices;
}


if (mesh->HasTextureCoords(0)) {
    float *texCoords = new float[mesh->mNumVertices * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; ++i) {
        texCoords[i * 2] = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
        texCoords[i * 2 + 1] = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[TEXCOORD_BUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[TEXCOORD_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * mesh->mNumVertices * sizeof(GLfloat), texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    delete texCoords;
}


if (mesh->HasNormals()) {
    float *normals = new float[mesh->mNumVertices * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; ++i) {
        normals[i * 3] = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
        normals[i * 3 + 1] = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
        normals[i * 3 + 2] = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[NORMAL_BUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[NORMAL_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * mesh->mNumVertices * sizeof(GLfloat), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    delete normals;
}


if (mesh->HasFaces()) {
    unsigned int *indices = new unsigned int[mesh->mNumFaces * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; ++i) {
        indices[i * 3] = mesh->mFaces[i].mIndices[0];
        indices[i * 3 + 1] = mesh->mFaces[i].mIndices[1];
        indices[i * 3 + 2] = mesh->mFaces[i].mIndices[2];
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[INDEX_BUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[INDEX_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * mesh->mNumFaces * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    delete indices;
}


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[MVP_LOCATION]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[MVP_LOCATION]);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(MVP_LOCATION + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(MVP_LOCATION + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * i * 4));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(MVP_LOCATION + i, 1);
}

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[MODELVIEW_MAT_VB]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[MODEL_VIEW_LOCATION]);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(MODEL_VIEW_LOCATION + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(MODEL_VIEW_LOCATION + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * i * 4));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(MODEL_VIEW_LOCATION + i, 1);
}

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[NORMAL_MAT_VB]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[NORMAL_MATRIX_LOCATION]);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_MATRIX_LOCATION + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(NORMAL_MATRIX_LOCATION + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * i * 4));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(NORMAL_MATRIX_LOCATION + i, 1);
}
```

Instanced Rendering

```
void MeshEntry::renderInstanced(std::vector<glm::mat4> mvps, 
std::vector<glm::mat4> modelViews, std::vector<glm::mat4> normalMats)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[MVP_MAT_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4) * mvps.size(), &mvps[0]
    [0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[MODELVIEW_MAT_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4) * mvps.size(), 
    &modelViews[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[NORMAL_MAT_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4) * mvps.size(), 
    &normalMats[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, elementCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
    NULL, mvps.size());

    // Make sure the VAO is not changed from the outside    
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 VertexTex;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 VertexNormal;

layout (location = 3) in mat4 MVP;                                                  

layout (location = 7) in mat4 ModelViewMatrix; 
layout (location = 11) in mat4 NormalMatrix;

out Data
{
    vec3 Position;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 TexCoord;
} data;


void main()
{
    data.Normal = normalize( NormalMatrix * vec4(VertexNormal, 0) ).xyz;
    data.Position = vec3( ModelViewMatrix * vec4( VertexPosition, 1 ) );
    data.TexCoord = VertexTex;

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4( VertexPosition, 1 );
    gl_Position = vec4( VertexPosition, 1 );
}
```

Again this code worked fine before I started sticking matrices in VBO's so the inputs are guaranteed to be fine.
I've only started tackling opengl in the last week, so forgive me for posting all the code I think might be relevant, as honestly I'm not sure what could be going wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a saved version of the original code that was working? It would be good to do a line-by-line comparison with it.

Comment: I have updated the question as I have new information, the objects were drawing but their MVP matrices were not being updated with the camera moving. The only difference between my new code and my old code, is that I was passing in the matrices 1 by 1 using glUniformMatrix4fv(), and calling the function DrawElements , instead of DrawElementsInstanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple error on my behalf, using the wrong variables as indices to the "vbo" array

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[MVP_LOCATION]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[MVP_LOCATION]);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(MVP_LOCATION + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(MVP_LOCATION + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
sizeof(glm::mat4), (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * i * 4));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(MVP_LOCATION + i, 1);
}
```

should be

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[MVP_MAT_VB]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[MVP_MAT_VB]);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(MVP_LOCATION + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(MVP_LOCATION + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
sizeof(glm::mat4), (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * i * 4));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(MVP_LOCATION + i, 1);
}
```

Notice the first and second line of each snippet

Answer (score 0):

change to :

```
layout(location =10)uniform  mat4 .. ;
```

(this runs with 430 shaders but not with say 330.There needed

```
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : enable
```

that stuff and most opengl 3.3 cards will deny it.)